# Get variable value from another function

Tags: c#

I have this function

```
public void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  //I get the value form a query..
  int MachineNo=Convert.ToInt16(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

i want to get the MachineNo from that function to this

```
 public void Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    bool edit=modify(MachineNo,UserName)
 }
```

Comment: Are both methods inside the same class?

Answer (score 4):

Change your `Search` function to:

```
public int Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   return Convert.ToInt16(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Then change `Edit` to:

```
 public void Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var MachineNo = Search(sender, e); 
    bool edit=modify(MachineNo,UserName)
 }
```

It's also not clear what `UserName` is in the `Edit` method, so make sure that's defined somewhere.  Also, in your example, `sender` and `e` are not actually used in the `Search` method so those could be removed from the method signature and the call.  If `Search` *must* match some delegate, you might have to create another `Search` method.

Comment: beat me by 4 seconds ):

Comment: Why do we have to call `Search` in `Edit`? the logic doesn't make much sense although it does solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @KingKing - I'm assuming there's a lot more to `Search` that we don't see in this example (eg, the database connection work), thus it needs to be abstracted in its own method.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, what is the purpose of `object sender, EventArgs e` in the function?

Comment: @DonA - None that I can see.  Perhaps its bound to an event handler and needs to match a certain delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the return type of your function?